# How do ListActivities work with ListViews in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

As a C# developer I'm trying to get familiar with Java and more specifically, the Android framework.

I've created some very basic intro Activities, but I'm now trying trying to get a ListView up and running with 'databinding'. I found this sample code: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

I don't think I've fully grasped the concept of these views yet, because initially I figured that the ListActivity class that I created would be built as some sort of a user-control that I could simply replace my ListView with. When I look at the code though, it appears as though it's somehow trying to hook into an existing view which confuses me. (How do I call this ListActivity from my current activity, and how do I use it with my ListView?).

```
getListView().setEmptyView(progressBar);
```

Could someone please clarify what's going on? Perhaps I've become too .NET paradigm orientated and I'm not understanding the picture properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ListActivity is an activity that assumes that you will set a layout with a list view in it with a certain id.  It will then store that view in a variable so getListVew() will return it.  Basically its a tiny bit of syntactic sugar to do what you can do yourself with 3 lines of code.

Really I don't think its worth using.  You can use listviews in a regular activity, it takes 1-3 lines of code to do everything the ListActivity does, and you don't have problems if you name your listview with a different id or if you even decide to not have a listview down the road.

Comment: Thanks. At first I was a bit confused, but after a bit of a challenge I now realize what you mean. I ended up using a regular ListView. I can't even remember what the point of using a ListActivity is.